# Select priority item from list

Tags: python

Say I have a descending ordered list in terms of preference:

```
person_choice = ['amy', 'bob', 'chad', 'dan', 'emily']
```

meaning, `amy` is preferred to `bob`, who is preferred to `chad` and so on.

And I have a couple more lists like these (with names appearing in no particular order and list length):

```
group1 = ['joyce', 'amy', 'emily', 'karen', 'rebecca']
group2 = ['chad', 'kyle', 'michael', 'neo', 'bob']
...
```

In each of the `group1` and `group2`, I would like to select the person within this list that appears in `person_choice` with the highest preference. So, an expected output is like this:

```
group1_choice = 'amy'
group2_choice = 'bob'
```

Assuming that for each `groupX`, there is at least one person appearing in `person_choice`, is there a one-liner to do this in Python without complicated `for` loop?

Comment: is it allowed to put all groups data into a single list? like 2D list

Comment: @adarsh No, each group is selected on its own, independent from any other group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `max` with a custom `key`:

```
person_choice = ['amy', 'bob', 'chad', 'dan', 'emily']

group1 = ['joyce', 'amy', 'emily', 'karen', 'rebecca']
group2 = ['chad', 'kyle', 'michael', 'neo', 'bob']


def choice(group):
    return max(group, key=lambda name: -person_choice.index(name) if name in person_choice else float('-inf'))


print(choice(group1))
print(choice(group2))
```

Result:

```
amy
bob
```

Comment: I would avoid `person_choice.index(name)` if the list gets much bigger.

Answer (score 4):

This is two-lines, but it should work:

```py
ranks = {
    person: i
    for i, person in enumerate(reversed(person_choice))
}

max(
    group1,
    key=lambda x: ranks.get(x, -1)
)
```

Essentially, we put our rankings into a dictionary for fast lookup. Then, we can use Python's `min` to search for our priority item. In this case, I reversed the list and used `max` so `-1` can be used as the priority for people not in the list.

Here's what it might look like in context:

```py
group1 = ['joyce', 'amy', 'emily', 'karen', 'rebecca']
group2 = ['chad', 'kyle', 'michael', 'neo', 'bob']
person_choice = ['amy', 'bob', 'chad', 'dan', 'emily']

ranks = {
    person: i
    for i, person in enumerate(reversed(person_choice))
}


def group_choice(group, ranks):
    return max(
        group,
        key=lambda x: ranks.get(x, -1)
    )


print(group_choice(group1, ranks))
print(group_choice(group2, ranks))
```

Comment: `ranks[x] if x in ranks else -1` can be replaced by `ranks.get(x, -1)`.